# LAG function with current row null and previous entry present

Tags: sql, oracle

I have used LAG function however unable to get records in which current row is null but previous row is present .

```
WITH DATA AS
(
Select 
COL_A ,
COL_B ,
COL_C ,
LAG(COL_C) OVER (PARTITION BY COL_B ORDER BY COL_A) PREV_COL_C 
from TABLE_COL
 )
 Select * from data where COL_A = '18-AUG-2022'
```

How to achieve the output with different ways?
Below is my data

[image]

I am trying to achieve below output

[image]

Comment: You are explaining the question incorrectly (even to yourself), which then leads to using the wrong approach in writing the code. In your input data, you **don't** have a row for `DD` for the date `18-Aug-22`. That is different from **having** a row where the value in `col_c` just happens to be `null`. First you need to generate such a row (for example by using an outer join to a calendar-like table or view). Then - general question - if there is an `EE` code for other dates, should you show that too, with `null` for both the current `col_c` and for `prev_col_c`? Need to clarify the problem!

Comment: Hi @mathguy , The problem statement , I am trying retrieve for date for 18-AUG  , And Since DD value is not present on 18-Aug .Hence output showing that Curr value is NULL but previous value is 300 .

Comment: Understood - but LAG only works for rows that exist in the input table, not for rows that don't exist in the input table. Then: If DD is not present on Aug 18 and also not on Aug 17, but it does exist on Aug 16, what is the "previous value"? Is it still NULL (not present on the previous day), or is it the value from Aug. 16? Note that LAG will give you the value from Aug. 16, ignoring the fact that DD doesn't have a value for Aug. 17 - is that what you need?

Comment: What should be an output if: 1) `EE` is present at 2022-08-19. 2) `FF` is present at 2022-08-16?

Comment: The query will always be run on two dates i.e. Current date and its Previous date .

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want one row for each value of `COL_B`, with `CURR_COLL_C` set to the value of `COLL_C` for the current date (or `null` if it has no value for the current date), and `PREV_COL_C` set to the previous value of `COLL_C` (or `null` if `COLL_C` is not set for any date before the current date). If so, this query should work:

```
select col_a, col_b, cur_coll_c, prev_coll_c 
from (
  select 
    trunc(sysdate) col_a, 
    col_b_values.col_b col_b,
    curr.coll_c cur_coll_c,
    prev.coll_c prev_coll_c,
    row_number() over (partition by prev.col_b order by prev.col_a desc) rn
  from data curr
  join (select distinct col_b from data) as col_b_values
  left join data as curr 
    on curr.col_a = trunc(sysdate) and curr.col_b = col_b_values.col_b
  left join data as prev
    on prev.col_a < trunc(sysdate) and prev.col_b = col_b_values.col_b
)
where rn = 1
order by col_b;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always have a single date and it's previous calendar date, then the task is much simplet and you may use conditional aggregation to distribute values between columns:

> ```
> with function something_that_provides_a_date
> /*May be replaced with binf variable or constant*/
> return date
> as
>   pragma udf;
> begin
>   return date '2022-08-18';
> end;
>
> select /*+gather_plan_statistics*/
>   something_that_provides_a_date() as col_a,
>   col_b,
>   max(case col_a
>     when something_that_provides_a_date()
>     then col_c
>   end) as curr_col_c,
>   max(case col_a
>     when something_that_provides_a_date() - 1
>     then col_c
>   end) as prev_col_c
> from input_tab
> where col_a in (something_that_provides_a_date(), something_that_provides_a_date() - 1)
> group by col_b
> ```
>
> | COL_A | COL_B | CURR_COL_C | PREV_COL_C |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 18-AUG-22 | AA | 400 | 100 |
> | 18-AUG-22 | BB | 500 | 200 |
> | 18-AUG-22 | DD | *null* | 300 |
> | 18-AUG-22 | СС | 600 | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=08418f42496094fb2a6a5970f5128531)*